# Show text from input field on different spots on html page

Tags: javascript, html, input

What I want to achieve is to input a text in an input-field and on submit I would like the text to appear in different spots of a HTML page.

Example: I have a page with the following lines

redcar- 
greencar-
yellowcar-

After I type in TEXT in the input field I want the lines to change to

redcar-TEXT
greencar-TEXT
yellowcar-TEXT

Is this possible achieve? If you have a sample code it would be very welcome.

This works for me

```js
function myFunction()
{
var x;


var person=prompt("Please enter your text","text");

if (person!=null)
  {
  x="redcar-" + person + "";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But I cannot get it to work for multiple lines

Comment: _“But i cannot get it to work for mutliple lines”_ - please _show us_, what you tried, instead of just giving us _that_. Please go read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create more `<p>` and change their content too.

I used [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML` because [it is considered bad practice to use `innerHTML` with user input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML)

```js
function myFunction()
{
    const person = prompt("Please enter your text", "text");

    if (person !== null)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "redcar-" + person;
        document.getElementById("demo2").textContent = "greencar-" + person;
        document.getElementById("demo3").textContent = "yellowcar-" + person;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
```

---

If you prefer to keep the static part always written, you can use innertag in your `<p>`s, I'm using `<span>` here as they are usually used for this.

also I removed the ids in favor of a class allowing me to loop over the element

```js
function myFunction()
{
    const person = document.getElementById("input").value;

    if (person !== null)
    {
        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("output")).forEach(el => {
            el.textContent = person
        })
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="input"><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>redcar-<span class="output"></span></p>
<p>greencar-<span class="output"></span></p>
<p>yellowcar-<span class="output"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this and just add all the "cars" you want to the `cars` array

```js
function myFunction() {
  const person = prompt("Please enter your text","text");
  const cars = ['redcar-', 'yellowcar-'];

  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars.map(c => c + person).join('<br>');
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to make the text appear in the p element in HTML. As you said, you want to input the text, and then on submit, you want it to be displayed in a p element. So here's what you can do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="carForm">
        RedCar: 
        <input type="text" id="redCar">
        GreenCar: 
        <input type="text" id="greenCar">
        YellowCar:
        <input type="text" id="yellowCar">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitBtn">

        <br><br>
        <p id="redCarP"></p>
        <p id="greenCarP"></p>
        <p id="yellowCarP"></p>
    </form>

    <script>
        const form = document.querySelector('#carForm');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        })
        $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
            $('#redCarP').text($('#redCar').val());
            $('#greenCarP').text($('#greenCar').val());
            $('#yellowCarP').text($('#yellowCar').val());
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Jquery and append html to a class or id. For more information: [Jquery Document](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
$( "p" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
```

```css
p {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<p>I would like to say: </p>
```